# Power amplifier design

Tags: rf, high-frequency, power-amplifier

For my research purpose, I am planning to design one power amplifier (basically, a current amplifier) with the following specification-

1. Frequency range: 0-100MHz (or at least 0-30MHz)
2. Output voltage: 30Vpp
3. Minimum output load: 3Amp
4. The input current is expected to be very low as it will be feed from a simple function generator (max output current is not specified in the function generator manual, but I think, they should be less than 30mAmp)

Initially, I was planning to use an RF op-amp but later realized, none of the commercial op-amps can drive such high current. What would be the most optimized design for this circuit?

Comment: Do you have a gain requirement, or is this a unity gain buffer?

Comment: input current would be very low as it will be feed from a simple function generator (max output current is not specified in the function generator manual, but I think, they should be ~30mAmp)

Comment: Amateur radio people build such devices all the time to act as as transmitters. You may want to look into these circuits

Comment: Could you please refer any exact reading material? I am a novice in this area.

Comment: Will the Zload be close to a pure resistance, or some ugly real world Z that best resides on a Smith Chart?

Comment: Oh my gosh, I forgot to mention the load type! The output of the amplifier is planned to connect with a hand-made Solenoid. Please let me know your opinion (my intention is to create a cheap AC magnetic field).

Comment: what inductance? Luh = a^2 * N^2 /(9a + 10b) with a=radius inches , and b=length inches, for single-layer tight-wound

Comment: I did not think about that yet. But my rough calculation says it should be something like this- N= 1000, radius = 5 cm, length = 10 cm, and current needed 1Amp

Comment: If your load solenoid is N=1000, then you can forget driving it with anything >100kHz

Comment: And what is the cheap ac magnetic field supposed to achieve i.e. what does it excite i.e. what is the real load.

Comment: Nothing... It will be supposed to be there just to create disturbance.

Answer (score 1):

Narrowband solutions may be preferable, with PI-network output tuning to "match" into your inductor/solenoid load, and the PI filtering will reduce distortion and random noise that may confuse your research results.  The amateur-radio people, for efficiency, may use class "C" on/off amplifiers, where PI-network filtering is required to meet harmonic interference restrictions; the "transmitters" have a 2-step process to change frequencies: at low power, tune the PI-network, then crank up the power. Given restrictions in radiated energy above 100KHz?, your 30 watt goal may have your local government investigating your research.

But if you want a broadband approach, something about like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq48hA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice there is NO short-circuit protection. And this circuit is AC_coupled.

The power output may be easier, if the final NPN and PNP are large MOSFETS instead, with large Safe Operating Area. The capacitances of the MOSFETS will be a challenge to drive at 30MHz.